# Trying to implement a search box in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Query not working:

> $attributes is an array which contains field names

```
public function search($table,$like,$attributes){  
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $attribute) {
         $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $attribute LIKE '$like%'");
         echo $this->db->last_query();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of `$attributes` array? Are attributes key-value pairs?

Comment: You are likely going to have to show more code in order for us to help.  Also, if search is a controller function, just a straight echo like that likely won't give you the data in the proper format.

Comment: Editing the title may also help to better identify your problem; the current one only fits as the first paragraph, not as a description of the issue you are trying to solve. People come looking for questions judging by their title.

Comment: Is there any error you are getting ?